# How do i set two navigation view from one side for example two navigation view should open from right to left at same time

Tags: navigationview

this is my navigation xml file i am trying to open two navigation view from one side but i am getting error stating that  java.lang.IllegalStateException: Child drawer has absolute gravity LEFT but this DrawerLayout already has a drawer view along that edge android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout.onMeasure(DrawerLayout.java:1074)

Feedpost.java

```
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton;
import android.support.design.widget.Snackbar;
import android.view.View;
import android.support.design.widget.NavigationView;
import android.support.v4.view.GravityCompat;
import android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarDrawerToggle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.example.kaush.scoreboard.R;

public class FeedPost extends AppCompatActivity
        implements NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener {
    DrawerLayout drawer;
    TextView tvSwipDescription;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_feed__post);
        Toolbar toolbar =  findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);



      drawer = findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);


        ActionBarDrawerToggle toggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(
                this, drawer, toolbar, R.string.navigation_drawer_open, R.string.navigation_drawer_close);
        drawer.addDrawerListener(toggle);
        //----------HIDE TOGGLE HAMBURGER ICON--------------
        toggle.setDrawerIndicatorEnabled(false);
        toggle.syncState();

        NavigationView navigationView =  findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
        navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);

        NavigationView navigationView1 =  findViewById(R.id.nav_right_view);




        navigationView1.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(new NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
                // Handle Right navigation view item clicks here.
                int id = item.getItemId();

                if (id == R.id.nav_settings) {
                    Toast.makeText(FeedPost.this, "Right Drawer - Settings", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                } else if (id == R.id.nav_logout) {
                    Toast.makeText(FeedPost.this, "Right Drawer - Logout", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                } else if (id == R.id.nav_help) {
                    Toast.makeText(FeedPost.this, "Right Drawer - Help", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                } else if (id == R.id.nav_about) {
                    Toast.makeText(FeedPost.this, "Right Drawer - About", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }

                drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.END); /*Important Line*/
                return true;
            }
        });

    }
//    private void initializeView() {
//
//        tvSwipDescription=(TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvSwipDescription);
//    }
    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        DrawerLayout drawer = findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        if (drawer.isDrawerOpen(GravityCompat.START)) {
            drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);

    } else

        if (drawer.isDrawerOpen(GravityCompat.END)) {  /*Closes the Appropriate Drawer*/
        drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.END);
    }
        else {
            super.onBackPressed();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.feed__post, menu);


        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }



        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("StatementWithEmptyBody")
    @Override
    public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle navigation view item clicks here.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        if (id == R.id.nav_camera) {
            // Handle the camera action
        } else if (id == R.id.nav_gallery) {

        } else if (id == R.id.nav_slideshow) {

        } else if (id == R.id.nav_manage) {

        } else if (id == R.id.nav_share) {

        } else if (id == R.id.nav_send) {

        }

        DrawerLayout drawer =  findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.END);
        return true;
    }

}
```

activity_feed_post.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:alpha="1"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    android:layout_gravity="right|center"
    tools:openDrawer="start">

    <include
        layout="@layout/app_bar_feed__post"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />


    <android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
        android:id="@+id/nav_view"
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:paddingBottom="96dp"
        android:clipToPadding="false"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        app:headerLayout="@layout/nav_header_feed__post"
        app:menu="@menu/activity_feed__post_drawer" >
</android.support.design.widget.NavigationView>


    <android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
        android:id="@+id/nav_right_view"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        app:headerLayout="@layout/nav_header_feed__post"
        app:menu="@menu/activity_main_drawer_right" />


</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```